# Regex for getting the title and the author from reference list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have parsed texts from several scientific pdf files. All of these files contain a reference list at the end, where the authors and their publications are listed, + when and where they were released. Also, there are cross-references in the text.

For example:

> ('1', ' I.  Altintas, C.  Berkley, E.  Jaeger, M.  Jones, B.  Lud-scher, and S.  Mock.  Kepler: An extensible system fordesign and execution of scientiﬁc workﬂows.  In In SS-DBM, pages 21–23, 2004. ')

and a different one from another text:

> ('1', ' G.  Antoniol, G.  Canfora, G.  Casazza, A.  DeLucia, and E.  Merlo,“Recovering Traceability Links between Code and Documentation,” IEEETrans.  Software Eng. , vol.  28, no.  10, pp.  970-983, Oct.  2002.')

I was able to recognize both with the regex, which gives me 2 capturing groups besides the full-match:

```
r'\(\'(\d+)\'\,\s\'(.*?\')\)'
```

The **first group** I can use to get the **number of the reference**, to match with the cross-references in text

The **second** is the **everything else remaining**, and i'd like to recognize the *author* and the *title of the publication* from it, regardless of the parsing format, if that's possible.

Later, I'd like to use these values to write separate `.txt` files with the author + title.txt name, and to append their cross-references found in the text to each file.

For this is what I have now for this:

```
for txt in os.listdir(txtDir):
    textFile = open(txtDir + txt, "r", encoding='utf-8')
    text = textFile.read()
    sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    references = re.compile(r'\(\'(\d+)\'\,\s\'(.*?\')\)', re.MULTILINE)
    line_list = []
    number_list = []
    publication_list = []
    ref_list = []

    for line in references.finditer(text):
            number, publication = line.groups()
            number_list.append(number)
            publication_list.append(publication)
            ref_list.append(line)

            for number in number_list:
                    number = number.replace(number, "["+number+"]")
                    for count, line in enumerate(sents):
                            line_list.append(line) 
                            if number in line and "]" not in line_list[count-1]:
                                    f = open(publication+".txt", "ab+")
                                    f.write(line.encode("utf-8"))
                                    f.close()
```

It was giving UnicodeEncodeError when I was trying to create a file with mode ="a+", for a suggestion i changed it to bytes.

It's not giving me an UnicodeEncodeError, it's giving me another now:

> f = open(author+".txt", "ab+")

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:` " A.  Yun chung Liu, “The Effect of Oversampling and Undersampling onClassifying Imbalanced Text Datasets,” master’s thesis, http://www. lans. ece. utexas. edu/aliu/papers/aliu_ masters_thesis. pdf, 2004. J.  Cleland-Huang, R.  Settimi, X.  Zou, and P.  Solc, “The Detection andClassification of Non-Functional Requirements with Application to EarlyAspects,” Proc.  Requirements Eng.  Conf.  (RE ’06), pp.  36-45, 2006. '.txt"

Currently the publication has everything else than the number from the references, **I'd like to switch that to author + title.txt**, and I hope that would solve the error above as well.

I'd appreciate every suggestion for improvement!

Comment: What is the type of author?

Comment: Don't make it yourself difficult by throwing in that trying to create (open? read?) files for the author right away. Start with something easy: print out the matched items and assure you got the basics right first.

Comment: @chrisz, author should be string; I'd like the regex to capture the author and the title as well in different groups (rather than the whole publication), then append them to an author_list and title_list

Comment: @usr2564301, Thanks, yes, I have checked if it is printing out the matches right. The code is finding them (however highly dependent on the parsing). I was interested, if it was possible to write out / append the matches to the author+publication title.txt they are related.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to create the desired capturing groups:

```
r'\(\'(\d+)\'\,\s\'(.*?\“|.*?\:)(.*?\”|.*?\.)(.*?\')\)'
```

Then I could write out the files, it looks correct as for these few occurences.